# How to get an MP3 bit rate in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, bitrate

I am searching for a way of getting an mp3 bitrate like `128kbps` or `320kbps` for mp3 audio from url link.

I have a `UITableView` that loads a list of files from url list, and I would like to display an audio quality.
I have tried using `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVPlayer` but no luck.
Please help, how can I achieve this?

```
 do{
       let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:audioURL)
       print(audioPlayer.settings)
       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                print(audioPlayer.format)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }catch {
            print("Error getting the audio file")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using the formula. It was that easy..

```
var bitrate: Int {      // kbps
        if size > 0 && duration > 0 {
            return size * 8 / 1000 / duration
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a variable name **sampleRate** of **AVAudioFormat** class. Did you try to call **audioPlayer.format.sampleRate**?

Comment: The sampleRate gives me the output of 44100.0, not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Extension**

```
import AVFoundation

extension AVURLAsset {

    var fileSize : Int? {
        
        let keys: Set<URLResourceKey> = [.totalFileSizeKey, .fileSizeKey]
        let resourceValues = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: keys)

        return resourceValues?.fileSize ?? resourceValues?.totalFileSize

    }
    
    // kbps
    
    var bitrate : Int {

        if (fileSize ?? 0) > 0 && duration.seconds > 0 {

            return Int(Double(fileSize ?? 0) * 8 / 1000 / duration.seconds)

        }
        
        return 0
        
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
// bitrate
    
let avAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: mp3Url)
    
let bitrate = avAsset.bitrate
print("avAsset.bitrate: \(bitrate)")
```