# Get bitrate os audio item swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, media-player

I need to get an Audio Item (remote) bitrate - 320, 128, etc. Found an answer - [How to get an MP3 bit rate in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715970/how-to-get-an-mp3-bit-rate-in-swift), but it doesn't work correctly. I can get a size of item, but my bitrate looks weird - like 154, 540.34, etc.
Help pls!

Comment: what's weird about how it looks?

Comment: All of them have bitrate 128 or 320. So it can not be 540.34. And this is weird

Comment: Do you have an example file you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solutions:
1. For local file:

```
func getSongBitrate(audioURL: URL, duration: Int, completition: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    do {
        let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: audioURL.path)

        if var fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as?  UInt64 {
            let dict = attr as NSDictionary
            fileSize = dict.fileSize()

            let kbit = fileSize/128//calculate bytes to kbit
            let kbps = ceil(round(Double(kbit)/Double(duration))/16)*16
            completition(Int(kbps))
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        completition(Int(0))
    }
}
```

2. For URL remote file:

   ```
   func getBitrate(audioURL: URL, duration: Int, completition: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {

       DispatchQueue.global().async {
           let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: audioURL)
           request1.httpMethod = "HEAD"

           var response : URLResponse?
           print("GO TO RESPONSE")
           do {
               try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1 as URLRequest, returning: &response)

               if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                   let size = httpResponse.expectedContentLength
                   let kbit = size/128;//calculate bytes to kbit
                   let kbps = ceil(round(Double(kbit)/Double(duration))/16)*16

                    // print("kbps === \(kbps)")

                   if self.songQuality == 0 {
                      self.songQuality = Int(kbps)
                  }

                   ////

                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       completition(Int(kbps))
                   }

                   ////

               }

           } catch (let e) {
               print(e)
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completition(Int(0))
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer requires AVPlayerItem, which in your case is a MP3 file. AVFoundation has a class [AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritemaccesslogevent) which can provide you with **AverageAudioBitrate**. So, you have to pass your AVPlayerItem to the following function:

```
func getBitRate(playerItem : AVPlayerItem) -> Double{
        //var event : AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent;
        var avgBitrate : Double = 0.0;
        for event in (playerItem.accessLog()?.events)!{
            if event.averageAudioBitrate>=0.0{
                avgBitrate = event.averageAudioBitrate;
            }
        }
        return avgBitrate;
    }
```

Since the APIs are exposed by apple,I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: AccessLog for every item in my list is nil.

Comment: Pass your AVPlayerItem after completion of its play.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will work only when the AVPlayerItem is passed after the completion of the playing event. I will update my answer once I come around with a work around.